# Multiple gridviews to single pdf using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to export multiple gridviews into single pdf using iTextSharp. I am looping through the gridviews and then looping through the rows of the gridview. The looping is going ok. But after pdf download, only the last gridview can be seen. It seems the gridviews are overwriting each other and only last one remains. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void btnExportToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { gridvw1,gridvw2,gridvw3 };
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);


            for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)
            {
                if (gvExcel[i].Visible)
                {

                    PdfPTable pdfTbl = new PdfPTable(gvExcel[i].HeaderRow.Cells.Count);

                    foreach (TableCell headerTblCell in gvExcel[i].HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        Font font = new Font();
                        font.Color = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
                        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerTblCell.Text));
                        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
                        pdfTbl.AddCell(pdfCell);
                    }


                    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvExcel[i].Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (TableCell tblCell in gvRow.Cells)
                        {
                            Font font = new Font();
                            font.Color = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].RowStyle.ForeColor);
                            PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tblCell.Text));
                            pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].RowStyle.ForeColor);
                            pdfTbl.AddCell(pdfCell);
                        }
                    }

                    //Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    pdfDoc.Add(pdfTbl);
                }
            }

            pdfDoc.Close();

            //Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report_" + startDate + "-" + endDate + ".pdf");
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your errors is not an iText error; it's is a simple logical error that can be solved with common sense. The other error is weird. You aren't using the `Response` correctly.

```
protected void btnExportToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { gridvw1,gridvw2,gridvw3 };
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);
        pdfDoc.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)
        {
            if (gvExcel[i].Visible)
            {

                PdfPTable pdfTbl = new PdfPTable(gvExcel[i].HeaderRow.Cells.Count);
                pdfTbl.SpacingAfter = 20f;

                foreach (TableCell headerTblCell in gvExcel[i].HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    Font font = new Font();
                    font.Color = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
                    PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(headerTblCell.Text));
                    pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].HeaderStyle.ForeColor);
                    pdfTbl.AddCell(pdfCell);
                }


                foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvExcel[i].Rows)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell tblCell in gvRow.Cells)
                    {
                        Font font = new Font();
                        font.Color = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].RowStyle.ForeColor);
                        PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tblCell.Text));
                        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(gvExcel[i].RowStyle.ForeColor);
                        pdfTbl.AddCell(pdfCell);
                    }
                }
                pdfDoc.Add(pdfTbl);
            }
        }

        pdfDoc.Close();


        byte[] content = ms.ToArray();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report_" + startDate + "-" + endDate + ".pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(content); 
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

There might be some other issues, but I hope you understand the logical error:

- You created a new PDF file with `PdfWriter` every time you entered the loop. You should only create one `PdfWriter` instance if you only want to create one PDF.
- It's better to create the PDF in a `MemoryStream`, and then write the content of that stream to the `Response` object as a binary stream. I really didn't understand what you were doing there (and why you tried to do it that way).
- I also introduced a `SpacingAfter` of 20 user units, otherwise it will look as if all tables all glued together into one big table.

There may still be some errors in the way you send the file to the `Response`, but this should already get you on your way. (Why aren't you sending the file size to the browser? You know that size, don't you? It's the number of bytes in the `content` object.)